# Appending an doublequotes and comma to value

Tags: python, for-loop, format

Consider the following code which consists of IP address as a result.

```
#loop through the list
for ip in ips:
        #I know there is argument as to whether the string join method is pythonic
        addy = "".join(ip)
        if addy is not '':
                print addy
```

Here Finally print addy will be printing the results simply(ie: IP address).

But Instead of that what I need is results should be printed in the following order.

Consider it having three results 1.2.3.4. 1.2.3.6 1.2.3.8.

It should be printed in the following format.

"1.2.3.4","1.2.3.6","1.2.3.8"

Note: Count of IP will be differ based on time.

Comment: `','.join('"{}"'.format(''.join(ip)) for ip in ips)`

Comment: Thank You.
Results is coming as follows:

"2.3.6.5","14.25.6.2","2.3.6.6",""

How to avoid comma and double quotes at last.

Comment: `','.join('"{}"'.format(''.join(ip)) for ip in ips if ip)`